# How does "latent_entropy" modify linux kernel functions?

Tags: linux-kernel, c

So in the linux kernel, we have the following function's method signature in /kernel/fork.c:

```
static __latent_entropy struct task_struct *copy_process(
                    struct pid *pid,
                    int trace,
                    int node,
                    struct kernel_clone_args *args)
```

What kind of C language feature is letting us use the __latent_entropy "attribute" (or what is it?) to modify this function?

I'm not necessarily asking in particular what latent_entropy does, since I googled that, I'm more curious about C method signature syntax. I didn't realize you could add extra flags like latent_entropy to a method signature. What kind of language feature is this / what can I google for to understand this better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a macro, which by default [is replaced by nothing](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.11/source/include/linux/compiler_types.h#L224):

```
#ifndef __latent_entropy
# define __latent_entropy
#endif
```

With GCC, in some cases [it becomes an attribute instead](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.11/source/include/linux/compiler-gcc.h#L60):

```c
#if defined(LATENT_ENTROPY_PLUGIN) && !defined(__CHECKER__)
#define __latent_entropy __attribute__((latent_entropy))
#endif
```

This is used by the GCC [entropy plugin](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.11/source/scripts/gcc-plugins/latent_entropy_plugin.c).

Comment: Thank you, now I know that "function attributes" is what I was looking for to google more.

Comment: Note that the entropy plugin is based on PAX_LATENT_ENTROPY and was later upstreamed.